# ajax call into jquery dialog box with unique ID

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog

can anyone help please,... 
I have a comments page with a link to report/spam that I want to call into dialog box with ajax,... how can I do this,..? thanks in advance,... 
here is my code:

```
<script>

$(function() {
 $('#photo_comments_opener_<?php echo $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'] ?>').dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 width: 500,
 modal: true,
 title: 'Report Photo Comment',

    open: function ()
    {
        $.ajax(function(){
            url: "<?php echo $html->url("/report/photo_comment/" . $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id']) ?>",
            data: data, 
            type: "post",
            sucess:function(msg){
                $('#photo_comments_opener_<?php echo $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'] ?>').html(msg)
            }
        });
   }       

});

  });
</script>
```

and here is the link:

```
<?php echo $html->link(ucfirst(__('report', true)), 'javascript:void(0)', array('id' => "photo_comments_opener_".$photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'], 'class' => 'report')) ?>
```

---

thank you for your reply Chintana,... however I could not succeed it,... 
I have a code that opens dialog box,... but I can't fit ajax call within:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#photo_comments_dialog_<?php echo $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'] ?>" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
width: 500,
modal: true,
title: 'Report Photo Comment'

});

$( "#photo_comments_opener_<?php echo $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'] ?>" ).click(function() {
  $( "#photo_comments_dialog_<?php echo $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'] ?>" ).dialog( "open" );
});

});
</script>
```

and here is the link:

```
<?php echo $html->link(ucfirst(__('report', true)), 'javascript:void(0)', array('id' => "photo_comments_opener_".$photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'], 'class' => 'report')) ?>
```

and here is ID div:

```
<div id="photo_comments_dialog_<?php echo $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'] ?>"></div>
```

please help me to accomplish this,... 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: you didn't say you problem, what is that?  the dialog isn't show or there is no content in the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

my PHP is not very good so I will try to structure my idea around javascript/jquery

I assume you are calling the display dialog part from a click of a button or a link. Why not go a step further with the success callback of $.ajax as you have done and do the dialog display within the it

Something along the lines of

```
function displayCommentDialog(){
    $.ajax(function(){
        url: "<?php echo $html->url("/report/photo_comment/" . $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id']) ?>",
        data: data, 
        type: "post",
        sucess:function(msg){
            $('#photo_comments_opener_<?php echo $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'] ?>').html(msg);

            var d = $('#photo_comments_opener_<?php echo $photo_comment['PhotoComment']['id'] ?>').dialog(
                {
                    // all your dialog options
                });

                d.dialog("open");
        }
    });
}
```